# Why can't I access the virtual terminal tty1 under VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have Ubuntu installed inside VMWare Workstation 8.  The host OS is Ubuntu 11.10.  When I boot Ubuntu, and login, all is OK.  But when I try to open console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> it does not.

I have VMWare tools installed.  How can I fix this?

Comment: you sure your laptop doesn't have function key?

Comment: Its not a laptop.  Its a desktop.

Comment: Oh, I suggest you look at the VMWare 8 manual.

Comment: Your edit completely changes the meaning of the question. The windows doesn't have a tty issue is what got the closing started. You shouldn't change meaning with an edit. They're for refinements, not reversals of meaning.  I would re-ask this question in its new form instead of editing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Enter full-screen mode first** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Click inside the Ubuntu VM (to make sure input is grabbed)
- Then try entering *tty1* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Works great for me here.

Answer (score 1):

Check if that keystroke combo is **not** being passed to Windows (host OS) instead. I have has similar issues with VirtualBox.

**Note:** *You are still running the standard Ubuntu binary **code**, but on quite different 'hardware'.  It is actually running on the **VMware 8** emulation of a PC, not your desktop PC. Some keystrokes are (by default) retained for passing commands back to the host.*