# ctrl+alt+f* is not working

Tags: keyboard, virtual-terminal

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on virtual box in Dell inspiron n5110. I have this problem from couple of weeks and did not get resolved yet after couple of searches.
Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+f(*) does not get me to a console. I am newbie.

How do I get this resolved?

Comment: I know that this http://askubuntu.com/questions/160289/why-cant-i-access-the-virtual-terminal-tty1-under-vmware question is closed, but take a look at izx's answer, does it help?

Answer (score 2):

In file /etc/default/grub, add `nomodeset` to the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="XXX"
```

becomes

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="XXXnomodeset"
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub.
```

Then restart.

Comment: Hadi I edited file but issue is not resolved yet.

Comment: can any one help me on this?

Comment: can any one give me suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

- Use <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>. By default, Virtual Box uses Right Control as Host Key.
- In some convenient cases where using USB keyboard, It could be attached directly to VM. So generic shortcuts could be used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>.